# powers of 2 java code help with my input different outcome

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PowersOf2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int inputPowersOf2;        
        int PowerOf2 = 1;   
        int exponent;
        int exponent2;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many powers of 2 would you like printed?");
        inputPowersOf2 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        if(inputPowersOf2 >= 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Here are the first " + inputPowersOf2 + " powers of 2:");
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Here is the first power of 2:");
            System.out.println();
        }

        exponent2 = 0;
        exponent = 0;
        while(exponent <= inputPowersOf2)
        {
            System.out.print("2^" + exponent2 + " = ");
            exponent2++;
            System.out.println((PowerOf2 = 2 * PowerOf2) / 2);
            exponent++;
        }
    }
}
```

why is it when i say give me 1 power of two it prints

```
2^0
2^1
```

and when i say give me 2 powers of two it prints

```
2^0
2^1
2^2
```

and so on...

Comment: Step through the code manually.  Figure out the value of each variable.  Consider it a learning experience.

Comment: What is the problem? Why is this a problem? What have you tried to do to solve the problem?

Comment: @JoeMcCay: +1 - This reminds me of when I was getting my CS degree and in THIRD year I was with a lab partner that not only never learned how to use a debugger but actively refused to even have me show him how to use it because apparently he viewed picking debugger as a learning burden that he did not to deal with.  OP, don't be that guy.  Debugger is your friend. So is general skills that you need to learn how to take a piece of software and figure out why it doesn't do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
while(exponent <= inputPowersOf2)
```

with

```
while(exponent < inputPowersOf2)
```

As others said in comments, this is very, very easy to solve using the debugger.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

You could retrace the steps manually on a paper using small inputs and then proceed to larger inputs.

just replace the code while(exponent <= inputPowersOf2) because it runs one extra time becuase of the "=" sign.